# Using strcmp() on STDIN_FILENO

Tags: c, strcmp

```
        char buf[BUF_SIZE + 1];
        printf("[Enter Command]: \n");
        num_read = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUF_SIZE);
        if (num_read == 5) {
            exit(0);
        }
```

I want to check if the user input is the string `"exit"` and exit the program if it is. The snippet above works but it will exit on all 4 letter strings. I only want it to exit on the string `"exit"`.

I don't understand why the code below doesn't work:

```
if (strcmp("exit", buf) == 0) {
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: What is `exit_call`? You haven't defined it anywhere. You can expect help only if you show all relevant parts of code.

Comment: @Binarus Sorry, I've updated the code

Comment: how is this failing?

Comment: You simply need to add the null byte after `read` call: `if (num_read > 0) buf[num_read] = '\0';`.

Comment: just add '\0' at the end replacing '\n'  buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0'

Comment: @NickS where exactly?

Comment: @static after read() and then use strcmp()

Comment: @static To understand what happens just use printf("[%s]\n", buf); after read and you will see that string contains line feed at the end. As you know all string should contains null terminator char at the end. So all magic is to replace '\n' to '\0';

Answer (score 0):

The `strcmp()` isn't working since `read()` is not 0-terminating the input, it's not doing string input.

Use e.g. `fgets()` to read a full line, then check if it starts with `exit` (remember that it will contain the linefeed).

Comment: https://pastebin.com/rHQmRUtg

Comment: I just receive a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` with this.